# Auto login after register with devise and doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

I currently have registration working (using Devise and Doorkeeper) but I am hoping that along with the user I can also automatically login the person and return their token information

So far I have tried to override after_sign_up_path_for

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/oauth/token'
end
```

but this didn't seem to do anything.

Any help? Or should I just call login from the api after register?

Comment: I don't know about Ruby and RoR but `call login from the api after register` is a pretty standard way of doing this in other languages and frameworks.

Comment: Do you have confirmation on? Do they need to be confirmed or anything?

Comment: @HassaninAhmed - no, as soon as they authenticate they can login

Comment: Did you create a custom controller to handle registrations? If so, check if your routes are pointing to it instead of the default devise registration controller.